# Python asyncio - how to await for retries in parallel

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm doing a bunch of async calls in parallel like so:

```py
txs = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch_tx_details(s["signature"]) for s in sigs])
```

These calls can sometimes fail and so I'm decorating each with backoff like so:

```py
@retry_with_backoff(10)
async def fetch_tx_details(sig):
    # stuff
```

Where backoff is defined like so:

```py
def retry_with_backoff(retries=5, backoff_in_ms=100):
    def wrapper(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            x = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    return await f(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Fetch error:', e)

                    if x == retries:
                        raise
                    else:
                        sleep_ms = (backoff_in_ms * 2 ** x +
                                    random.uniform(0, 1))
                        time.sleep(sleep_ms / 1000)
                        x += 1
                        print(f'Retrying {x + 1}/{retries}')

        return wrapped

    return wrapper
```

The problem I have is that if any of the calls fail, they are retried sequentially rather than in parallel. Eg I'm trying 1000 calls, 100 fail - I now have 100 sequential calls that are executed (slow) rather than having 100 parallel calls (fast).

How do I change my code to parallelize retries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Don't use `time.sleep()`**. That will completely block execution,  including other coroutines. Always use the [`asyncio.sleep()` coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) in asyncio tasks as that'll yield execution to other tasks that are not blocked:

> `sleep()` always suspends the current task, allowing other tasks to run.

You are already using a loop, if you switch to `await asyncio.sleep(...)` then the task will pause and let others run until the retry wait time is over:

```
def retry_with_backoff(retries=5, backoff_in_ms=100):
    def wrapper(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            x = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    return await f(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Fetch error:', e)

                    if x == retries:
                        raise
                    else:
                        sleep_ms = (backoff_in_ms * 2 ** x +
                                    random.uniform(0, 1))
                        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_ms / 1000)
                        x += 1
                        print(f'Retrying {x + 1}/{retries}')

        return wrapped

    return wrapper
```

Anywhere `await` is used in a coroutine control can be passed back to the event loop to switch tasks. The connected `await` calls are the thread from event loop to the current point of execution in asyncio tasks, and the means by which a coroutine can *co-operate* to allow other tasks to do work every time there is reason to wait for something. Like waiting for enough time to have passed.

`time.sleep()`, on the other hand, waits without handing control over to other tasks. Instead, *the whole thread* is blocked from doing anything, and here that means the asyncio event loop is blocked, and so the other tasks can't execute either.